# Better way to restart (XAML-)Designer in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, designer, restart, xaml-designer

Currently when i have a problem (like errors and warnings, that are resolved but are still present in the ErrorList or to reload assemblies used by the designer) with the XAML-Designer in Visual Studio 2012 and i need to restart it, i open ProcessExplorer and kill the child-process `XDesProc.exe` of the running Visual Studio 2012 instance. This results in that Visual Studio 2012 displays an Unhandled Exception `Designer process terminated unexpectedly!` and provides me the option to reload the designer.

Is there a better or build-in way in Visual Studio 2012 to restart the designer. Reopening XAML-Files often do not help to solve the problems.

Comment: Recompiling the application do the trick for me. But in order for that to work, the assembly must have changed (otherwise VS is clever enough to not reload anything -_- )

Comment: I just installed Update 2 for visual studio 2012, I'm getting this less often, but still getting it...

Answer (score 1):

My solution (credit to Ellistraee)

- close VS and blend
- delete the bin and obj folders in your solution
- delete any .user files
- delete any .suo files
- open vs and blend
- open the offending page which would crash the designer - you should get a "please build the project" message
- F6 to rebuild the solution

And it should work!

Comment: Wow that sounds easy! Only six minutes to get a basic function going. Atleast it's faster than waiting until the editor itself decides to do something...

Comment: It sucks, yeah. My solution stopped working though and I'm now getting RemotingExceptions with any design data binding (half the usefulness of Blend, gone). Apparently some of my XAML is dodgy...

Comment: Yep, it worked for me. I had no .user file[s], but deleted the bin and obj folders and the suo file, restarted, and voila! Thanks a million X pi!